# Mailgun API Routes: Emails are sent multiple times

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, email, mailgun

I'm having a problem understanding why emails that are forwarded to an API endpoint from a Route on Mailgun are sent multiple times. 
I am trying to create an instance of a model on Mongoose and for some reason it creates it multiple times.

Here's my code for the endpoint

```
EmailController.post("<endpointname>", 
 function(req,res) {
  let now = new Date();
  let isoString = now.toISOString();

  Announcement.create({
   title: req.body['Subject'],
   description: "",
   author: req.body['From'],
   author_id: "",
   club: "",
   date: isoString,
   content_html: req.body['body-html'],
   clicks: 0
 },
 function (err) {
  if (err) return res.status(500).send({ event_created: 
   false})
  res.status(200).send({ event_created: true});
 });
})
```